# Dope Sheet copy/paste buffer keyframes problem

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I have an issue with keyframes in the dope sheet editor.

When I select all my bones, keyframes and copy them, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and all keyframes are pasted except IK Bones, Pole Bones and a few others. The Icon for this don't work as well.

A. The First screenshot shows, that I Copy all the keyframes.
[image]

B. The Second screenshot - Keyframes don't paste.
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (or at least a part of it, like several bones of your armatures)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I don't know what did you pressed, but I can't find that 4 keyframes in animation 
(these missing on Pic. B). You know, when I press Buffer copy/paste key - (I don't know correct name for it) then if I play animation, first step is fine, but second step is stucked on one 0,0,0.. Anyway , I'll be very glad , if you can describe me how did you fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem of name, don't use "left" or "right", you need to recall all the **XXX Left** with **XXX L** or **XXX_L** or **XXX.L**, and also make sure all your bones are selected in the 3D view before you <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>.

About the left fingers: If Blender can't find any bone with **R**, it can't mirror the right to the left, so give the suffix **R** to the right fingers.

Comment: Thank you moonboots, this little _ helps , I never had problem with this before, anyway thank you. Cheers.

Comment: it looks like it's rather "Left" and "Right" that can't be used  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably got your answer after 5 years, but for the next person coming across this problem, the problem for me was the graph editor. Just go to the graph editor and copy those keyframes instead of the dope sheet keyframes.